# How to write a query in order to achieve the orderby descending clause for an uninitialised generic collections such as List of integers in c#?

Tags: c#, linq

with your help what I'm going to do as a practice is I'm trying to write a small console application which allows the user to insert a number, then it stores it in a collection and illustrates the input in a descending manner to the console.
As a new programmer I would say I hope what I'm said is making sense.
Here is what I've written.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<int> list = new List<int>();
        var inpt = Console.ReadLine();
        var parsedInpt = Int32.Parse(inpt);
        list.Add(parsedInpt);

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var query = from n in list
                        orderby n descending
                        select n;
            Console.WriteLine(query);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with list of one item?

Comment: Maybe you want to split input number into digits and then sot them ? I mean for example you input 1324 and get 4321 in the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're a little confused how LINQ works

You wouldnt run your query inside a loop, you'd run your query (LINQ will loop internally) and then you might use a loop to pull the results out. The query runs when you start to pull results out and then your loop consumes the results (iterates over them)

```
        var query = from n in list
                    orderby n descending
                    select n;
        foreach (var item in query) {
          Console.WriteLine(query);
        }
```

If you're meaning to print the list out every time the user enters a new number, demonstrating that no matter what they enter you'll sort it, that might be a valid reason to run your query in a loop:

```
 while(true){
     list.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));

     var orderedList = list.OrderByDescending(x => x);

     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", orderedList));
 }
```

With this the user repeatedly enters ints and every time they do, the updated list will be sorted and printed descending. If they entered 3 then 1 then 2, they would see "3", then "3,1", the "3,2,1" printed out..

This answer contains the two different styles you might see LINQ queries - method syntax (`list.OrderByDescending(x=>x)`) and query syntax `from x in ...`. The two are complimentary and there are quite a few things that are neater to represent in query syntax (joins for example) that can get into a bit of a mess with method syntax.. Pick your poison, and swap and change as you like ;)

Comment: Thank you for your comment Caius Jard.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var list = new List<int>();

var input = "";
do
{
    input = Console.ReadLine();
    if (int.TryParse(input, out var parsedInpt))
    list.Add(parsedInpt);
} while (input.Length > 0);


list.OrderByDescending(x => x)
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

User will input values until wrong format or empty string would be provided.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Ivan Khorin.

Comment: **Please** don't suggest the anti-pattern of combining `ToList`+`ForEach` to iterate over a collection, especially to a new dev. It has to iterate the full collection 2x, allocates at least one, likely multiple arrays (for the list's backing array) along with multiple array copies/resizes, allocates a delegate+potential closures, involves 2 method calls and likely other things. **Please!** just use a normal `foreach` over the result of `OrderByDescending`. Use `ToList` if you *must*, (ie. you need the results further and don't want multiple enumerations of the root) but use a plain `foreach`!

Comment: Ivan May I ask you what does out var parsedInpt do in the if statement, please?

Comment: @Navid, sorry, I'm not a good teacher, so the best I can do is to suggest two articles: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier  - the official MS docs, https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/out-parameter-in-c-sharp-7/ - maybe it help, too. I want to say that int.Parse() will raise exception if you pass wrong format (not integer) that you will need to handle. TryParse() will just return true if string have been converted correctly https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-5.0 have a nice day.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, no, I won't use "normal fpreach" for just one Console.Writeline() command, lol. The question was about Linq , I showed how to use it with linq. What a problem you see? Are you sitting for hours to optimize your code, or do it fast as you like and optimise if really acts too long?

Comment: @IvanKhorin, Thank you for your comprehensive response. I appreciate it and you have a good day too.

Comment: Well, `List<T>.ForEach` is *not* LINQ. It's just a method that accepts a delegate. In my experience as both a former teaching assistant and a lead engineer/architect, teaching bad habits causes those bad habits and others to multiply. There's nothing more disconcerting then a codebase littered with ToList+ForEach all over the place, calling ToString on strings, using exceptions for flow control and a hundred other things that could've been nipped in the bud had the developers learned better in the first place

Comment: @pinkfloydx33, ok, i see, that we have just different "religions". Someone use "" to initialize empty string, someone use string.Empty(). It is just a company choice what to include into internal rules. I repeat: there is no reason to use full `foreach` construct for printing  less then 100 strings.